# How to auto pause video when scrolling / when the player is not visible on screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, video, video-player

I am working with a video player called 'flick video player'. I can play videos fairly okay with default functionality. The problem occurs when I scroll down the screen and the video continues to play in the background. I would like to pause it when it isn't visible, or when a user navigates to a different page on the project app.

The video player that I am using (flick_video_player) has video_player as its dependency.

Answers are much appreciated.
Regards

Comment: (Well, if you posted some code, we wouldn't need to guess details) If you are using `ListView.builder` you can pause your video in dispose method (again, assuming your video is wrapped in stateful widget.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can use visibility detector for the purpose-

```
VisibilityDetector(
                            key: ObjectKey(flickManager),
                            onVisibilityChanged: (visibility){
                              if (visibility.visibleFraction == 0 && this.mounted) {
                                flickManager?.flickControlManager?.pause();//pausing  functionality 
                              }

                            },
                            child: Container(
                              child: AspectRatio(
                                aspectRatio: 1280/720,
                                child: FlickVideoPlayer(
                                    flickManager: flickManager
                                ),
                                /*VideoPlayer(
                                    video_controller
                                ),*/
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
```

I was working on something similar. For more info like how to play it again and more you can refer this repo- https://github.com/GeekyAnts/flick-video-player/tree/master/example/lib/feed_player

Hope it helped!

Comment: The problem was solved in a similar manner. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your list of videos with a `NotificationListener` and listen to whether the user has started or stopped scrolling. Use this value to either play or pause your video.

Edit: misread your question. This will work for pausing once the user scrolls. If you want to detect whether the video is within the current view, check out [ScrollablePositionedList](https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list).

```
return NotificationListener(
  onNotification: (notificationInfo) {
    if (notificationInfo is ScrollStartNotification) {
      // Set a state value to indicate the user is scrolling
    }
    if (notificationInfo is ScrollEndNotification) {
      // Set a state value to indicate the user stopped scrolling
    }
    return true;
  },
  child: YourVideos(),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it might be a very intuitive way of solving it. I, however, was able to solve it by looking at one of the dependencies' examples and had to do a little tweaks :) Cheers!

Comment: I didn't even know VisibilityDetector was a thing, seems like a very handy tool, thank you!

Comment: @Rohit Can you provide a hint as to how you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this visibility detector package can help https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I was already using visibility detector. Had to do a little tweaks here and there :)

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what you need, [inview_notifier_list](https://pub.dev/packages/inview_notifier_list):

```
InViewNotifierList(
  isInViewPortCondition:
      (double deltaTop, double deltaBottom, double vpHeight) {
    return deltaTop < (0.5 * vpHeight) && deltaBottom > (0.5 * vpHeight);
  },
  itemCount: 10,
  builder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return InViewNotifierWidget(
      id: '$index',
      builder: (BuildContext context, bool isInView, Widget child) {
        return Container(
          height: 250.0,
          color: isInView ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
          child: Text(
            isInView ? 'Is in view' : 'Not in view',
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did a few tweaks here and there after looking at the dependecy's example and was able to solve it :). Would certainly try your approach if I get stuck in future... Cheers